# Could you please explain what the ffmpeg script does?

Tags: ffmpeg

There is this script:

`ffmpeg.exe -t 1 -i "D:\input\3.mp4" -ss 1 -i "D:\input\3.mp4"  -i "D:\input\3.mp4" -filter_complex "[1]zoompan=z='if(lte(mod(time,2),1),2,1)':d=1:x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2):s=1920x1070:fps=25/1'[s0];[0][s0]concat=n=2 [outv]" -map [outv] -map 2:a -b:v 500k -s 1920x1070 -c:v h264 -vsync 2 "D:\output\3.mp4" -y`

I need to understand what he is doing, comment on each step so that I understand. Why are the three input files the same, what's going on at all? I really hope for you.

Answer (score -1):

Let me take a stub at it. Here is the command reduced down to bare minimum only showing relevant options:

```
... 
-filter_complex [1]zoompan=...[s0];[0][s0]concat=n=2 [outv]" 
-map [outv] 
-map 2:a 
...
-vsync 2
...
```

This filter chain produces a video first showing the full view of the input video followed by a zoomed view (`-vsync 2` is alluding changing the framerate to 25 fps).

If 1 input stream is used for both original and zoomed, all the input frames must be buffered before zoomed frames are generated. Duplicating input stream allows the first one to be consumed to pass the original view and use the second for the zoomed version.

The 3rd input is used for audio `map 2:a`. This is somewhat odd and unnecessary. You could very well do `map 0:a` without the 3rd input. The true oddity is that this audio will only be present during the first part of the output video and not during the 2nd zoomed part.

Comment: This can be done with just one input.  Add `+1` to `time`.